# Access rights for node_modules folder at MacOS/Linux and Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, access-rights

I'm developing some nodeJS applications on a mac machine. For testing purpose I'm using Parallels to get a virtual windows machine (win 10).

If I'm running `npm install` for a project on my mac, I can't run the project on the windows machine, as I'm getting an `access denied` error for the node_modules folder.

So I deleted the folder an run `npm install` on the windows machine. With that I can run the app. But then on my mac machine I do get e.g. `sh: /Users/project/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: Permission denied`.

What can I do to set the correct access rights to the node_modules directory to get the app running on both OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the binaries (.bin) compiled in macOS need not necessarily work with windows too.
For your scenario, use YARN. Because YARN offers offline install.

*Reference link*: https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/

In either of your systems install YARN.

1. `npm install yarn`
2. Inside your project folder in a cmd or a terminal just type `yarn`
    -Yarn will start resolving your packages.
3. Once done, create a `.yarnrc` file by executing the following commands (same for both windows and macOS).

   `yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror ./npm-packages-offline-cache`

   `yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true`
4. A `.yarnrc` file will be created in your home directory (`macOS => ~/.yarnrc || windows => C:\{user}\.yarnrc`).
5. Move that file into your project to make it specific only to your project.
6. Now do a `yarn install` -> Results in `node_modules` folder and a `yarn.lock` file. Also note that in the home directory under the folder `npm-packages-offline-cache` you will have all the dependencies in tarball format.
7. All you have to do is **Commit this tarball directory and the yarn.lock** to a repository common to both the environments, setup yarn in other environment by repeating the same 1-5 steps.
8. Finally run yarn install -offline, you will have the dependencies loaded.

Long story, Short! You can't just copy paste node_modules and get it working between windows and unix.

Hope it helps you..